# Why does behavior of `./example` and `sh example` different? (`zsh: text file busy: ./example`)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kernel, sh

I tried this:

```
$ exec 3> example
$ lsof example 
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
zsh     10711 lane    3w   REG  253,0        0 9231034 example
```

It will show `text file busy` if I do this:

```
$ ./example  
zsh: text file busy: ./example
```

But if I execute it using `sh`, it will be OK(no error):

```
$ sh example 
$
```

What is the difference between `./example` and `sh example`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
$ ./example
```

you are trying to `execute` "example" which is being written to. This is not allowed.

When you do

```
$ sh example
```

`sh` is `reading` "example", then execute what is read. This is fine.

Answer (score -1):

There are different shell environments on the Linux, such as `sh, bash, zsh and etc`.
In some shells, there are differences in the execution of the bash script.
when you use `./example` it execute the script in the current shell.
when you use with `bash example`  or `sh example` it will run on the the specific shell you want.
also you can use [shebang](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang#:%7E:text=It%20is%20called%20a%20shebang,specified%20on%20a%20first%20line.) in the first line of you script.